# Undefined index when loading page

Tags: php, html, mysql

When the page loads i get the undefined index error message enumerated 7 times, I assume it's 1 message per variable.

When I click submit all the form data still get submitted to the DB.

Once I submit the form the Undefined Index error goes away! on page reload.

Weird

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","project1");
// Check connection
        if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }
// check variables set
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $site_code = $_POST['site_code'];
    $site_name = $_POST['site_name'];
    $site_address = $_POST['site_address'];
        $site_city = $_POST['site_city'];
    $site_postalcode = $_POST['site_postalcode'];
    $province = $_POST['province'];
        $country = $_POST['country'];
}
// Query from Countries table
$query_countries = "select * from countries";
$country_results = mysqli_query($con,$query_countries);
$number_of_returns_country = mysqli_num_rows($country_results);
// Query from Provinces Table
$query_provinces = "select * from provinces";
$provinces_results = mysqli_query($con,$query_provinces);
$number_of_returns_province = mysqli_num_rows($provinces_results);

//insert form values into sites table
$sql_site="INSERT INTO sites (site_code, site_name, site_address, site_city, site_postalcode, id_province, id_country)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[site_code]','$_POST[site_name]','$_POST[site_address]','$_POST[site_city]','$_POST[site_postalcode]',$_POST[province],$_POST[country])";
mysqli_query($con,$sql_site);        
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="site.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Insert Site into DB</h1>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/index.html>Home</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/insert.php>add site</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/delete.html>delete site</a></h2>
    <h2 class="button"><a href=/search.html>search site</a></h2>
        <form class="insert" action="insert.php" method="post">
                <h3>Site Info</h3>
                        Site code: <input type="text" name="site_code"><br>
                        Site name: <input type="text" name="site_name"><br>
                        Address: <input type="text" name="site_address"><br>
                        City: <input type="text" name="site_city"><br>
                        Postal code: <input type="text" name="site_postalcode"><br>
                        Province: <select name="province">
                                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($provinces_results)){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['province'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select><br>
                        Country: <select name="country">
                                        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($country_results)){ ?>
                                        <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['country'];?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                </select><br>
                <h3>Site Contact Info</h3>
                        Site contact name: <input type="text" name="site_contact_name"><br>
                        Phone number 1: <input type="number" name="site_contact_number1"><br>
                        Phone number 2: <input type="number" name="site_contact_number2"><br>
                        Email address: <input type="email" name="site_contact_email"><br> 
                        <input type="submit">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: usually it tells you what line it is on, however glancing at your code, I'd suggest that `$site_code = $_POST['site_code'];` might want to be something along the lines of: `$site_code = isset($_POST['site_code']) ? $_POST['site_code'] : '';`  since there are seven of them.

Comment: @jackgould Notice: Undefined index: site_code in C:\wamp\www\insert.php on line 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because, when you load your page for the first time, data of the form isn't set. When you compile and send it, the error doesn't show up simply because now data is set.

Comment: Replacing <input type="submit"> with <input type="submit" name="submitted"> and putting your php code into the condition if(isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
//here your code
}

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error, because there is no data in your $_POST variable. To fix it, you will have to add a name to your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="form_posted">
```

and enclose your PHP code into this if:

```
if(isset($_POST['form_posted'])) {

}
```

Alternatively, you can add this on top of your PHP, to exclude warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_WARNING);
```